# Why does rails generate a migration with a timestamp three hours ahead of the current time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my country the time is 15:52:39.When I generate a ,model the timestamp on the migration is equivalent to 18:52:39. That's three hours ahead of the current time.

```
rails generate model Article title:string text:text

      invoke    active_record
      create    db/migrate/20140512185239_create_articles.rb
      create    app/models/article.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create    test/models/article_test.rb
      create    test/fixtures/articles.yml
```

Why doesn't the timestamp on the migration match my current time?

Comment: Cant understand your question.Please explain a bit more.

Answer (score 3):

Rails uses UTC timezone for migrations, not your local one. See the relevant [code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb#L712):

```
def next_migration_number(number)
  if ActiveRecord::Base.timestamped_migrations
    [Time.now.utc.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"), "%.14d" % number].max
  else
    "%.3d" % number
  end
end
```